# Could I revert events on an element to state before manipulation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For my current project, I have an issue concerning event handling. The problem is that I have to add event listeners to an element and remove the events when the given element is closed. To simulate my problem, rather than making things complicated by opening and closing elements, I will present a couple buttons that will represent what should happen at certain occurrences:

```js
//This event listener was added elsewhere in the script, or in another script:
$("#foo").on("click", function() {
  alert("You just clicked on \"Foo\" button."); //<-- Do not remove this with $.off(), this would be the default event.
});

//This would be my own custom code (please do not remove vanilla/plain javascript here for the solution, as that will be the direction I want to be going for my project):
document.querySelectorAll("#add").forEach(node => node.addEventListener("click", function() {
  $("#foo").on("click", function() {
    alert("Another event has been added to \"foo\" button.");
  }); //<-- How to remove only this event (or any newly event added with this button), and not the default event given above?
}));

$("#remove").on("click", function() {
  $("#foo").off(); //<-- Do not remove default event with this, how? Or how to revert to default event?
});

$("#revert").on("click", function() {
  //How could I revert whatever events were assigned to the "#foo" button (before the event(s) were removed by "#remove" button and before it was manipulated by the "#add" button)?
})
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button id="foo" class="btn btn-default">
  Execute event(s)
</button>

<button id="add" class="btn btn-default">
  Add event(s) to previous button
</button>

<button id="remove" class="btn btn-default">
  Remove event(s)
</button>

<button id="revert" class="btn btn-default">
  Revert back to default event
</button>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8c9toa37/)

I would like the "Remove event(s)" button to only remove the newly added event(s). Or I would like to keep it working this way and get the final button to work (so that I could use the required code to combine it with the removal of the functions, which in turn will result into the same behaviour I am looking for).

Could I "save" the default event on the `<button id="foo">` in some way before removing any events on it (with in this case jQuery's `$.off()`)? Could I make an exception for `<button id="foo">` on the removal of events?

Comment: Could you do somethiing like `function realThingy() { whatever; whatever }; function fake() {}; var proxy = realThingy; $('#foo').on('click', () -> proxy() ); ..... function swap() { proxy == realThingy ? fake : realThingy }` .... saves you the hassle of removing and adding functions all the time

Comment: I do not really get what point you are trying to make, could you show a working example and explain? @Tibrogargan

Comment: i would suggest to add and remove a `data-attribute` to the element. on your `click` event, check if the `data-attribute` is there and run your function, or dont if it dosent exist.

Comment: also check: https://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-custom-events/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you would do using the regular DOM API:

```js
function defaultListener() {
  console.log("You just clicked on \"Foo\" button.");
}

function additionalListener() {
  console.log("Another event has been added to \"foo\" button.");
}

foo.addEventListener("click", defaultListener);

add.addEventListener("click", function() {
  foo.addEventListener("click", additionalListener);
});

remove.addEventListener("click", function() {
  foo.removeEventListener("click", additionalListener);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button id="foo" class="btn btn-default">
  Execute event(s)
</button>

<button id="add" class="btn btn-default">
  Add event(s) to previous button
</button>

<button id="remove" class="btn btn-default">
  Remove additonal event
</button>
```

The key to being able to remove an event listener is ***passing a reference to the handler function*** to `el.removeEventListener(eventName, handler)` (which is why I put the code in two named functions `defaultListener()` and `additionalListener()` rather than the anyonymous functions your code used).